# What's the difference between “int a[5]” and int (*a)[5], int a[5][4] and int (*a)[5]? (C only)

Tags: c, arrays

What is "a" in each of the above cases, a pointer or an array. Please explain in detail. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should try this site: [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org/).  Have fun with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `int a[5]`  `a` is an array of `5` `int`.
2. `int (*a)[5]` `a` is a pointer to an array of `5` `int`.
3. `int a[5][4]` `a` is an array of `5` array of `4` `int`.
4. `int *a[5]` `a` is an array of `5` `int` pointers.

Comment: is int (*a)[5] same as int *a=(*int)malloc(5*sizeof(int));

Comment: I think #3 is backwards: 5 arrays of 4 `int`s each, or maybe I'm just having trouble parsing the sentence.

Comment: @Apvast no, not like that, because int that case memory is allocated on the heap, it's more like `int b[5]; int *a = b;`.

Comment: It looks more like an exam question where the OP failed.

Comment: Oops, no homework... Can you tell me some really good reference to such concepts.

Comment: [Read this](http://www.compsci.hunter.cuny.edu/~sweiss/resources/c11standard.pdf)